# Google Maps SDK for Android development in Eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, maps

I am doing a tutorial on Google Maps for Android but when I go to download the Google Maps SDK and open the Google Inc tab in the SDK manager it says "No packages found".

I've tried everywhere on the net but couldn't find anything and I think if I leave it much longer the men in white suits will be taking me off somewhere. It's probably a simple solution so if anyone could help me to get this SDK without re-installing eclipse that would great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstal, update manager, eclipse and your os. Maybe only manager and eclipse ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the package problem by updating the SDK manager

You can do it from here:

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
```

by doing that you will be asked to to update the ADT when you open eclipse again, you can follow the instructions here:

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
```

The only problem for me was that the deploy of apps to device or emulator does not work anymore. So be careful what you wish for. I haven't been able to fix that yet.